# What argument must i pass for this letter instance function

Tags: vb.net

I need to make a function that counts the instance of each letter from a string from a to z and storing it into an integer array. I'm pretty bad at working with parallel arrays so please bear with me thanks. So far I have:

```
 Function Letter(ByVal strTest As String) As Integer()
    Const intMaxLetters As Integer = 25
    Dim intLetters(intMaxLetters) As Integer
    Dim value As String = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
    Dim chrLetters() As Char = value.ToCharArray
    Dim intCounter As Integer = 0
    For intCounter = 0 To strTest.Length - 1
        Dim c As Char = strTest.Substring(intCounter, 1)
        If c >= chrLetters(0) And c <= chrLetters(25) Then
            **intLetters()** += 1
        End If
    Next
    Return intLetters
End Function
```

What argument must i pass on intLetters to add 1 to each element? Of course intLetters(0) representing char a and intLetters(25) representing z. Thank you!
Also, if i was to use this array in more than one control (like two buttons on the form) then what scope should i be using? thanks!

Comment: well, if it is less than the min and more than the max, you store nothing nowhere, right?  BTW `value` is 16 chars not 25

Comment: sorry i meant a to z let me fix that and the min and max

Comment: `Dim lcounts = str.ToLower.ToCharArray.GroupBy(Function(g) g).Select(Function(s) New With {.Key = s(0), .Count = s.Count}).ToArray()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your specific question, the index into the intLetters array is the difference between the ASCII value of the character and the ASCII value of "a".

I would also simplify you code in a couple of ways:

- Rather than create a string containing all the lower case letters, you can use the `Char.IsLower` method to check if a character is a lower case letter.
- You can loop through all the characters in a string by using a For/Each loop (a string can be treated as an array of characters).

Here is the simplified function.

```
Function Letter(strTest As String) As Integer()
    Dim intLetters(25) As Integer
    For Each c As Char In strTest 'use strTest.ToLower if you don't care about the case of the letter
        If Char.IsLower(c) Then intLetters(Asc(c) - Asc("a"c)) += 1
    Next
    Return intLetters
End Function
```